# Mapbox: Indian GPS co-ordinates show wrong place on map

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-marker, mapbox-gl-draw

I am trying to use the JS version of mapbox in my web application. BUt when changing the example lat-long to delhi's latlong its showing wrong location.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Display a map</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.54.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.54.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='map'></div>
<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoid2ViZXhwZXJ0c3VqZWV0IiwiYSI6ImNqdmh4MXM0dDAwMWs0NXFyNHkxc2o1eGwifQ.jgbBoS14uvv8i_lMrCQF5A';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map', // container id
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11', // stylesheet location
    center: [28.6466773,76.813073], // starting position [lng, lat]
    zoom: 9 // starting zoom
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Is this a case of swapped co-ordinates, ie does Mapbox expect *long,lat* rather than the near-universal convention of *lat, long* ?  Just guessing, the map tile you show is high-latitude (`~76N`) and east longitude (`~28E`).  Or, on closer reading of your comments, have you made the switch ?

Comment: please explain more, I am not aware about the swapped co-ordinates. I am using the latlong getting from google map or html5 location service.

Comment: If one interprets `28.6466773,76.813073` as latitude+longitude the coordinates specify a point off the north coast of Europe, as your picture shows.  If one interprets them as longitude+latitude they specify a point in India.  The almost-universal convention is to specify geo-coordinates as latitude+longitude.  If I look at what you have posted you appear to think that they are longitude+latitude, but the map tells a different story.

Comment: Oh, got it. Its working now. As you said Its an issue of swapped co-ordinates.

Comment: It's not that universal. https://macwright.org/lonlat/

Answer (score 0):

As [High Performance Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/44309/high-performance-mark) mentioned, MapBox uses swapped co-ordinates that means they are not using:

```
[lat, lng]
```

they are using

```
[lng, lat]
```

Try to change it and then try again.